# How to perform whole program optimization for LLVM bitcode files

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, llvm, clang

I have several LLVM bitcode files which I link with `llvm-link` to create one bitcode file. However, `llvm-link` does not perform Whole Program Optimization (WPO). How can I link bitcode such that the linker also performs WPO for producing the final bitcode file.

Comment: Use `opt`, specifically with `-adce -argpromotion -constmerge -globaldce -globalopt` and of course all the normal `-O1` passes.

Comment: clang can devirtualize: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-fwhole-program-vtables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimizations will be performed when using [llc](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) to compile the bitcode file. Alternatively, use [opt](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/opt.html) to invoke the optimizer directly.

Just using clang should also *do-the-right-thing*.